# Could not open ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js in the editor

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, terminal

react native terminal error

When running on Windows, file names are checked against a whitelist to protect against remote code execution attacks. File names may consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods, dashes, slashes, and underscores.
Loading dependency graph...Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly did you do to receive the error message you mentioned?